# R issue while loading library xlxs - Error : cannot allocate vector of size 3.6 Gb

Tags: r, memory-management, xlsx

I am trying to load `library(xlsx)` in R but getting below mentioned error:

```
Loading required package: rJava
Error : cannot allocate vector of size 3.6 Gb
In addition: Warning messages:
1: package ‘xlsx’ was built under R version 3.1.3 
2: package ‘rJava’ was built under R version 3.1.3 
3: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) :
  Reached total allocation of 4028Mb: see help(memory.size)
4: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) :
  Reached total allocation of 4028Mb: see help(memory.size)
5: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) :
  Reached total allocation of 4028Mb: see help(memory.size)
6: In get(Info[i, 1], envir = env) :
  Reached total allocation of 4028Mb: see help(memory.size)
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
```

I installed package `rJava` as well but get similar error while loading library `rJava` as well. I don't have any java knowledge. Please help how I can fix this error. I don't have java installed on my machine.

Comment: If not mistaken, `rJava` clearly needs java to be installed.

Comment: @Pascal is right, you first need to install Java on your machine.

Comment: And to avoid some memory limitations, add this line `options(java.parameters = "-Xmx16g")`